# gfortran different versions

Tags: 18.04, compiling, gcc

[image]In my **Ubuntu 18.04** , default **gfortran is 7.5**. But default **gcc** version is showing **8.4.** I have already installed **gfortran-8.4**.
I need to make my default gfortran version as 8.4. How to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install gfortran version 8.4 in Ubuntu 18.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gfortran-8
```

You may need to use `update-alternatives` <sup>[link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7832892/)</sup> to set the gfortran version if you have two or more different versions of gfortran installed. To change the default version of gfortran type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gfortran gfortran /usr/bin/gfortran-8 60 
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gfortran gfortran /usr/bin/gfortran-7 40 
sudo update-alternatives --config gfortran
```

Comment: Excellent. I had trouble with one executable, which threw random SIGSEGVs. It was apparently compiled with a mix of gcc8 and gfortran7. Choosing gfortran8 with your method fixed the problem. Thank you.